# Excel find exact substring in cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Using Excel formula, how do i find an exact substring match in a cell?

For example:

**Returns true if,**

substring: "AUS"

string: **AUS** Disaster recover site

**Returns false if,**

substring: "AUS"

string: Disaster Recover is important bec **AUS** e it ensures business continunity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the "AUS" you're looking for will always be capitalized, you can use `FIND` with an `ISERROR`. If the text you're evaluating is in cell A1, you can use the following formula

```
=IF(AND(ISERROR(FIND("AUS ",A1)),ISERROR(FIND(" AUS",A1))),FALSE,TRUE)
```